# Android Studio apk file not showing up

Tags: android, command-line, apk

I installed Android Studio on my system and would like to run my tutorial app ("MyFirstApp") via the command line instructions. The app shows up on my Android phone just fine and I can run it through the IDE by clicking the Run button, but command line does not seem to be working for me.

I followed the instructions to the letter by going to the root of the project ~/AndroidStudioProjects/MyFirstApp, then entered the gradle command, but MyFirstApp-debug.apk was not created in the apk directory. What I did see was a file named app-debug.apk.

Just to see what would happen I ran the command and altered it based on what was in the apk file, **adb install app/build/outputs/app-debug.apk**, but the terminal complained "command not found".

If there is anything someone can recommend so that the appropriate file is created in the apk directory it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: did you run the command "adb" to see if it is in your path? did you run as root?

Answer (score 0):

I think you chose the "debug" option of "Build-type" instead of "release".

1. Click on Build->Generate Signed Apk...
2. Next.
3. [Then click on "release" like in this picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/klOH5.jpg)
4. Finish. Check the APK destination folder: e.g "AndroidStudioProjects\YourApp\app\app-release.apk"